# gcc macro when -fprofile-generate is used

Tags: gcc, pgo

Does gcc define a macro of some sort when the flag `-fprofile-generate` is specified? Basically, I want to disable multithreading when I'm profiling--it seems to have a way of corrupting the .gcda files.

Comment: Profiling running something different than the "normal" load/configuration makes little sense.

Comment: @vonbrand Eh, do you think I'd bother if I could just let the code run as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This unanswered question is quite old, but I was having similar issues, so I hope this can be useful to someone.

You should try enabling the `-fprofile-correction` GCC compiler flag when using the profile information generated by a multi-threaded application. According to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) relative to this flag:

> Profiles collected using an instrumented binary for multi-threaded programs may be inconsistent due to missed counter updates. When this option is specified, GCC uses heuristics to correct or smooth out such inconsistencies. By default, GCC emits an error message when an inconsistent profile is detected.

It will get rid of the errors indicating that the .gcda files are corrupted by correcting inconsistent profile values due to multi-threading.

Comment: So I have this situation where I working with a multi-process program. Would -fprofile-correction help in that case?

Comment: Quite possibly, yes. Why not give it a try and see if it helps in your case? :)